# How do I test an image's .RawFormat against a List<string> of extensions from Web.Config?

Tags: list

I want to put the allowed extensions for an image upload in the web.config for easy modification later. what I have here currently works but is hard-coded.

```
if (!img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png)
                        && !img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Gif)
                        && !img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                        && !img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Bmp))
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Wrong Image Type. Please use an image one with the following extenstions:<br /><b>.jpeg, .gif, .png, or .bmp</b>";
                        return View(location);
                    }
```

This is what I was trying, but I need to pass in an ImageFormat not a string... How do I accomplish this?

```
                        bool isAcceptedType = false;
                    List<string> AcceptedImageTypes = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AcceptedImageTypes"].Split('|').ToList();
                    foreach (string s in AcceptedImageTypes)
                    {
                        if (img.RawFormat.Equals(s))
                        {
                            isAcceptedType = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isAcceptedType)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Wrong Image Type. Please use an image one with the following extenstions:<br /><b>.jpeg, .gif, .png, or .bmp</b>";
                        return View(location);                
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer [here](http://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2014/june/getting-systemdrawingimagingimageformat-from-a-string/) on this page..